# Reading Multiple values from a config file in C

Tags: c, scanf, config

Need to read multiple values from a config file/parse it and write them(values only) into another file.

Code Snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
    FILE *fp;
    int a[50],i=0,j;
    fp=fopen("Config_1.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error in opening the file \n");
            return 1;
        }
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i])!=EOF) 
        {
           i++;
           fgetc(fp);  // For going to the next line
        }

    fclose(fp);
    /* writing to another file */
    return 0;
    }
```

My config file(txt file) is similar to this:

```
Audio Left: <value>
Audio LVol: <value>
Audio Righ: <value>
Audio RVol: <value>
```

The above one works if the config file variable names are the same. i.e the length and convention as above.
But if variable name changes like this:

```
  Audio Left: <value>
  Audio RighT: <value>
  Audio LeftVol: <value>
  Audio RightVol: <value>
```

then Text2.txt file the output is:

```
Audio Left: <value>
Audio RighT: <value> // Value read fails
Audio LeftVol: <value>  // This one here fails. I get a garbage value here & rest follows
```

Can you please help on how to read only values [Regardless of variable name]?

Comment: Show a [mcve] (including all `#include`s) as well as a real minimal config file that triggers the problem. Read this: [ask]. Also indent your code properly.

Comment: Use `strtok` to break each line up into tokens with `':'` as the delimiter.